# Diagnostic Tools on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2022

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 and ran an existing ASPNETMVC 4.8 application with IISExpress on the Visual Studio 2022. When the application came to the start page, the process memory shows about 400MB on the Diagnostic Tools, it used be around 200MB on Visual Studio 2019. Both shown below are running the same application.
Anybody know the reason? and does the high memory usage make the application slow?

[Visual Studio 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Umi.png)

[Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBYBN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because **Visual Studio 2022** is a *64-bit application* now. It will use double the memory as before. Make sure you have at least 4 gigs or RAM memory, though 8+ is better.

Note: Many people are also reporting freezes of the IDE because of the memory use but in combination with Windows Security exploit prevention systems and the new VS 2022 debugger "VsDebugConsole.exe". When blocked it has some weird memory leak. I will be posting a security fix for this in stackoverlow soon.